# OpenLayers 4 remove features.getFeatures() sort array on change

Tags: openlayers

I added the function drag on a feature that I draw, but OpenLayers 4 seems that when you modify a feature, the new index of the one you modify now is different.

How can I remove that function from the core? or exist an alternative to prevent this?

This is what I use to add the drag function.

```
$("#markdrag").click(function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  var sel = document.getElementById('tlfeature');
  // get ID of the current marker
  var ids = sel[sel.selectedIndex].id;
  var dragInteraction = new ol.interaction.Modify({
    features: new ol.Collection([Msource.getFeatures()[ids]]),
    style: null
  });
});
```

Here my Marker source and layer for the feature.

```
Msource = new ol.source.Vector();

markLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: Msource,
  style: new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon({
      opacity: 0.95,
      src: 'http://www.traffweb.uk/images/mapplot.svg'
    })
  })
});
```

Here the function I call when to populate the select element:

```
function drawingMarker(){

  var id = Msource.getFeatures().length;

  $('<option>', { 'value': id, 'text': 'Marker ' +(id + 1) }).attr('id',
                 id).appendTo('#tlfeature');

  $('<textarea>', { 'name': 'Marker ' +(id + 1), 'rows': '4', 'class': id,
                   'placeholder': "enter text..." }).appendTo('.textDiv');

}
```

Where IDS is the index of the feature, but if I draw 2 features and drag the 1st at the end of the interaction the index is now 1 and not 0.

I need to work on Index because when I draw a marker I have a function that:

- populates the drop-down menu with the marker (name = Marker + source index)
- add a Textarea (bind to the marker ID(source index) so when you change the marker you have a related Textarea)

I'm working on this events to create all of these.

```
mark = new ol.interaction.Draw({
  source: Msource,
  type: Type
});

markLayer.on("change", function(){
  // remove the interaction when you plot one marker 
  // at this point, Msource is populated. This is called also when I use the
  // delete button(I remove the feature).
  map.removeInteraction(mark); 
});

// occurs when you finish to draw the current element
// at this point Msource is still empty
mark.on("drawend", function(){
  // function to create everything
  drawingMarker();
})
```

here a screenshot of how it looks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, when you change a feature, its index will always at the last of the result of getFeatures().This is operating mechanism in openlayers.

See API : [getFeatures().](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.source.Vector.html#getFeatures) It uses random order!

Anyway, I come up with a way that not the best but can do your favor. Use id to track marker. Just like:

```
var len = vector.getSource().getFeatures().length;
var feature = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geom.Point(coordinate),
    image: 'img/mark_b.png',
    id: len
});
vector.getSource().addFeature(feature);
```

and get it by `vector.getSource().getFeatureById()`.
Modify your code as following:

```
$("#markdrag").click(function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  var sel = document.getElementById('tlfeature');
  // get ID of the current marker
  var ids = sel[sel.selectedIndex].id;
  var dragInteraction = new ol.interaction.Modify({
    features: new ol.Collection([Msource.getFeatureById(ids)]),
    style: null
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I was thinking about something like your solution but I don't know how to implement it on my code, I update my question in order to show you how I populate and create the features.

Comment: @Sebastiano According to my understanding, your code implements that click on the map to add a marker, select the drop-down item to modify certain  feature at one time. delete the related item after remove the feature. Is that true?

Comment: @Sebastiano I think you'd better assign a static counter to marker's id. Because removing feature will change the length of the result of `getFeatures()` that would be equal to some created feature.

Comment: yes, I have 3 buttons (just 1 for the marker) when I click on them I activate the draw function and start the draw when you click on the map with the mouse. When you finish drawing I populate the select element. Now I can choose the one I want and locate, drag or delete it (I can unset instead of delete) the problem is I can't have the `featurebyId` I added to my code `Msource.getFeatures()[Msource.getFeatures().length - 1].setId(Msource.getFeatures().length - 1);` when you finish to populate the `select element` and then `Msource.getFeatureById(ids)` but it returns me `null`

Comment: if I use this to have the ID it works `markLayer.getSource().getFeatures()[0].getId()` but I need to iterate the source and have the correct `ID` not select one and get the `ID`

Comment: At the end I found out how to do it, I use `setId` var like `counter` `ids` and `index` and it seems to work